# MySQL: update column with data from another column

Tags: mysql

I am trying to fix some wrongly placed data for a pretty important column in my table.
The data in **Column1** should be in **Column2**, however, I need to update Column2 with Column1 data for each row up until a date, say 2020-10-20.

Any suggestions on how to do this safely?

**My two columns:**

```
Column1  Column2
150      -0.5
151      -0.13
155.5    10.33
165.4    1.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
UPDATE Table1 SET Column2 = Column1 WHERE mydayte <= '2020-10-20'
```

Comment: Worked great it seems, safe and sound. Thanks!